# Django: Find mutual likes for all users

Tags: python, django

I have a model of recorded likes by one user of another:

```
class Like(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="like_owner")
   likee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="like_likee")
```

And I want to know the best possible way to get an output of all the users who have at least 1 mutual like. Right now I have a solution where I basically iterate over each users 'like_owner' list counting the number of times where they are also named as matching likee, but this seems inefficient.

Any idea how to solve this with clever aggregation?

Edit to add my (bad) code:

```
users #list of preselected users I wish to find mutual matches for
for u in users:
    #check if user has requested contacts and is also at least 1 requested contact to reduce costly queries
    if u.like_owner.count() > 0 and u.like_likee.count() > 0:
        all = u.like_owner.all()
        for r in all:
            m = Like.objects.filter(r.likee=u, owner=r.likee).count()
            print m
```

Comment: Could you post your code here?

Comment: I edited it to show the code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are better solution. Try `gt` or `gte`

```
User.objects.filter(like__likee__gte=1)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He need users with atleast 1 **mutual like** :)

Comment: Yes, as @skbly7 said. This would only show me users who got any likes, no?

Answer (score 0):

For Django queryset I am thinking, but if you are fine with raw query. This should be probably best way.

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (select fv1.owner_id as ui1, fv2.owner_id as ui2 from Like fv1 LEFT JOIN Like fv2 ON fv1.likee_id = fv2.likee_id where fv1.owner_id != fv2.owner_id) as a`

Comment: Thank you for this. I am trying to run it:

 for p in Like.objects.raw('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (select fv1.owner_id as ui1, fv2.owner_id as ui2 from Like fv1 LEFT JOIN Like fv2 ON fv1.likee_id = fv2.likee_id where fv1.owner_id != fv2.owner_id)'):
        print p

but am getting an error: subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (select fv1.owner_id as ui1, fv2.owne...

Comment: sorry my bad. updated the query, just add `as a` at end of query.

Comment: Really sorry that I can't debug myself as I am new to raw queries. It now raises the error that the relation "like" does not exist. Am I doing it right that I run the raw query on Like.objects.raw(...) or do I need to run it on User? Edit: Fixed it now, had to use the actual table name

Comment: I got it to run like this:
from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (select fv1.owner_id as ui1, fv2.owner_id as ui2 from like fv1 LEFT JOIN like fv2 ON fv1.likee_id = fv2.likee_id where fv1.owner_id != fv2.owner_id) as a')
    total_rows = cursor.fetchone(). But, the result is empty even though it should not be

Comment: @sike what is the table name in your database, it is because table `like` wouldn't be in your database. it was used by me as sample table name, as exact name wasn't given in question. replace it with the actual table name.

Comment: Yep, but I have already accounted for that. I got previous errors when I used the model name instead of the actual table name. Using the actual table name removed the errors but just resulted in an empty result